# How can I call a nested function from outside its parent function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am working on an HTML file with JavaScript in it.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var dImage = new Image();

var drawing = (function () {

    .
    .
    .
    .

    redrawing = function () {
        context.drawImage(dImage, dX, dY, dWidth, dHeight);
    },

    init = function () {
        dImage.src = "images/d.png";
        redrawing();
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };

}());

function updateImage(dSrc){
    dImage.src = dSrc;
    // Call redrawing here
}
```

In the HTML I call

```
drawing.init();
```

and it is working fine. Also I can change the image source by calling

```
updateImage("images/d2.png");
```

and it is working for changing the source.

But I need to call `redrawing()` in the method `updateImage()` to refresh the image.

I try to call it in many ways (for example, `drawing.redrawing();`) but there is no response from `redrawing()`.

Comment: This is intended behavior — `redrawing` appears to be explicitly out of visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to call the `redrawing` function from outside of the function it’s defined in, you need to return it from that function, just like you’ve done with `init`:

```
var drawing = (function () {

    .
    .
    .
    .

    return {
        init: init,
        redrawing: redrawing
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `redrawing` public:

```
return {
    init: init,
    redrawing: redrawing
};
```